# minikube not starting the service

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, terminal, minikube

I was trying to deploy nginx using kubernetes, I set up all the things accordingly but when I executed command "**minikube service my-app**"  it was showing error :

❌  Exiting due to MK_UNIMPLEMENTED: minikube service is not currently implemented with the builtin network on QEMU

I followed each step according to tutorial but It went wrong. Did GPT search but it didn't worked for me.